# How can I use Javascript to handle form data & display a separate results page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am re-writing a large web form that is written using Perl Dancer and Template Toolkit to handle the submitted form data and display a results page. I would like to abandon Template Toolkit and Dancer in favor of a Javascript-only solution. How can I write the form to pass all of the data to Javascript and have it display the data on a nice formatted results page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I will use HTML5 sessionStorage. Here is the code:

form html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Form test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id='form' action="result.html" rel="external">
        <input name='day' id='day' type='text'><input type='submit' id='completed' value='Completed!'>
    </form>

    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the main.js:

```
function saveData() {
    var submit = document.getElementById('completed');
    submit.onclick = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('day', document.getElementById('day').value);
    };
}

window.onload = function() {
    saveData();
};
```

Here is the result html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="stuff"></div>

        <!-- SCRIPTS -->
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="result.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the result.js:

```
function displayData() {
    var div = document.getElementById('stuff');
    div.innerHTML = "<p>" + sessionStorage.getItem('day') + "</p>";
}

window.onload = function() {
    displayData();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what kind of data you have that could be entered in your form, so I don't have any specific help with how you could present that data in a nicely formatted way.

On the topic of passing data from a form to javascript (or jquery, since that was in your tag) here is an example of how you could accomplish this.

Let's say you have a simple form in HTML laid out something like this.

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" id="input">
</form>
```

You can catch the submission event of this form in javascript, prevent what it would normally do, take the data from it's input fields and do something specific with them. Here's an example.

```
// On DOM loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Catch the submit event of the form
  $('#form').submit(function (e) {
    // Prevent default form submit event
    e.preventDefault();
    // Access some input field data
    var input = $('#input').val();
  });
});
```

I would be happy to point you in a more specific direction on how you could format and present your data in a nicely formatted way if you would like to provide some more information as to what data you would be passing from your form.

Comment: I have gotten this far, and that's exactly the kind of simple data I'm using, but how do I take the input value and push it to a new, separate results page? With Template Tool Kit, I would have the form start like this:  <form id='form' name='form' method='POST'>
and in the results page, I would have lines like this:  <span class="item">Name: </span><span class="info"><% params.firstName %> <% params.lastName %></span>